# Removing console.log Breaks Code with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm playing with the Web Audio API and using this code:

```
function playTones(startFreq, numNotes) {
  if (numNotes === 0) return;

  var osc = AC.createOscillator();
  osc.frequency.value = startFreq;
  osc.onended = function() {
    playTones(startFreq + 20, numNotes-1);
  };
  console.log(osc.onended);

  osc.connect(AC.destination);
  osc.start();
  osc.stop(AC.currentTime + 1);
}
```

It's just supposed to play a series of notes, each one 20Hz higher than the previous. However, when I remove the `console.log` it doesn't work; it only plays the first note and then stops with the `onended` callback never being called. Why would this happen? Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Define `osc` outside of your `playTones` function, and pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/d3m041o6/ (using Chrome 47 on Windows). Also, I don't see why it should change your code behavior, sadly

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird that that fiddle works... Is it wrong to assume that that `onended` callback will fire while `osc` still exists? In other words, is the function returning and then the `onended` callback is called for `osc` but it's out of the callstack now so nothing happens?

Comment: No IMO there's nothing related to wrong callstack. But look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/d3m041o6/2/, the function is only called 3 times. I bet the culprit is `osc.stop(AC.currentTime + 1);`: `osc` is reseted everytime `playTones` is called, but `AC` is not, and maybe at some point, the song is stoped while not even started, so the `onended` could not be called. I don't know Web Audio API enough to help you any further.

Comment: This is a known bug in Chrome.  Hopefully it will be fixed soon. (CL almost ready.)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could try this:

```
    var AC = new AudioContext();

   function playTones(startFreq, numNotes) {
   if (numNotes === 0) return;

   var osc = AC.createOscillator();
   osc.frequency.value = startFreq;

   //    console.log(osc.onended);

    osc.connect(AC.destination);
    osc.start();
    osc.stop(AC.currentTime + 1);
    setTimeout(function(){playTones(startFreq+20,10)},1000);
    }

    playTones(200, 10);
```